# Why is getNetworkOperator not reliable for CDMA?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cdma

Can anyone say why the documentation for the `getNetworkOperator` function of `TelephonyManager` states that this can return unreliable result for CDMA ?

[getNetworkOperator documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperator%28%29)

`Availability: Only when user is registered to a network. Result may be unreliable on CDMA networks (use getPhoneType() to determine if on a CDMA network).`

What kind of results are you getting when calling this method on a CDMA device ?
and if it's not reliable, How can I get the MCC for a CDMA device ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe is useful to other people.

I don't know what returns from some CDMA networks, but i believe will be a "null" for sure.

You can get the MCC from [getSimOperator()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimOperator%28%29).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but truth is that so far looks like this is working pretty good which makes me even more suspicious about the comment in documentation..

Answer (score 0):

It is unreliable because it can be kind-of spoofed on cdma networks. You can get actual operator names like Verizon Wireless but you may also get strings like HOME, CRICKET, SCHOOL etc.